# Can somebody help me to find the appropriate word for a course that thorough, fast and useful?

Tags: single-word-requests

all
I have a problem to find the good word for describing a course that is thorough, fast (in short time) like seminar and fruitful. Is it possible for me to use words 'a straightaway course'?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 'Module' might fit your purpose https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=strict&q=meaning+of+module+in+education&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOj5KEqOjYAhVSe8AKHcnnCgsQ1QIIkAEoBA&biw=1280&bih=669

Comment: Intensive, perhaps?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I believe it asks for a term to describe what in most circumstances is an impossibility (a course that is thorough but of short duration).

Comment: perhaps ''thorough -> through'' and the question is only about a quick course?

Answer (score 1):

You may use **crash course**

> **crash course:** a course that teaches you a lot of basic facts in a very short time.

Eg: I did/took a crash course in French before my trip to Paris.

please check [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/crash-course)

Comment: Possibly as close an answer as one is going to get, but crash courses, rather than being thorough, cover the basics.